# Ruby missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function in my controller and i would render to another page, called thankyou. Render works fine, but after that rails redirects me again to thankyou, but this time it can't find the template. I can't understand why rails renders me two times to the same template, with differents results. This is my function:

```
def create
amount = params[:amount]
nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
if nonce.nil?
  render :checkout
else
  result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    amount: amount,
    payment_method_nonce: nonce
  )
  session[:user_id] = nil
  render :thankyou
end
end
```

This is the form that calls the action create:

```
<%= form_tag '/create', remote: true, id: "form", method: "post" do %>
 <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
  Choose you plan: <br>
  <div>
  <input class="collection_radio_buttons" id="plan_pro" name="amount" type="radio" value="0.99">
  <label for="plan_pro">
  <span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
  <b>Pro</b><br>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input class="collection_radio_buttons" id="plan_premium" name="amount" type="radio" value="1.98" checked="checked">
  <label for="plan_premium">
  <span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
  <b>Premium</b><br>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div id="paypal-container"> </div>
  <input data-braintree-name="number" placeholder="Card number" class="string optional form-control input-box mailcode-form" maxlenght="16">
  <input data-braintree-name="cvv" placeholder="CVV" class="string optional form-control input-box mailcode-form" width="3" maxlenght="3">
  <input data-braintree-name="expiration_date" placeholder="Expiration date (e.g. 10/20)" class="string optional form-control input-box mailcode-form">
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
     <input type="submit" class="signup-next" id="button_1" value="Pay 0,99 €">
     <input type="submit" class="signup-next" id="button_2" value="Pay 1,98 €">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

PS: from the log it seems that rails called action create twice. This is the actual log after i've submitted the form:

```
    Started POST "/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-30 15:47:06 +0200
Processing by HomeController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S2LG9Bg4TrbXOoU4ewDBXHr0J1xtawrXy9hdSVjCBzA=", "amount"=>"1.98", "payment_method_nonce"=>""}
  Rendered layouts/_social.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered home/_thankyou.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered home/thankyou.js (4.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16127ms (Views: 8.4ms)
[Braintree] [30/Jun/2015 13:47:38 UTC] POST /transactions 422


Started POST "/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-30 15:47:22 +0200
Processing by HomeController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S2LG9Bg4TrbXOoU4ewDBXHr0J1xtawrXy9hdSVjCBzA=", "amount"=>"1.98", "payment_method_nonce"=>"695c94a3-d219-44b6-af6f-cfec5dbb445f"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16376ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template home/thankyou, application/thankyou with {:locale=>[:it, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/marco/Scrivania/mailcoding_web/app/views"
  * "/home/marco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:117:in `create'


  Rendered /home/marco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

Comment: I can see that there is a missing `end` in that snippet.  Is there anything else after that end that might make `:create` do more?

Comment: No it's a my mistake

Comment: I edited my answer.  I think when you hit :create, and render the templates your code chooses, you're falling through to show :create, maybe?  Try a `return` after the `if`?

Comment: Yes i try. It doesn't work

Comment: OK, well, something is not being translated when you tell me about the logs.  If you could copy/paste the actual log, it would push us to the answer a lot faster. 

Comment: What's thankyou.js doing?

Comment: I paste the actual log. This is the file thankyou.js:
$('#signup-modal .modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript(raw render('thankyou')) %>");

Comment: You have a second render right there. Can you try it without loading the javascript in the view and see if it stops misbehaving?

Comment: Now it is saying that you don't have a template app/views/home/thankyou.html.erb.  Do you have that, or just the partial?

Comment: If i don't load the javascript rails simply doesn't find the template thankyou, but it still calls create twice

Comment: I have only the partial. If i add a template rails finds it and render me twice: one times at the partial and one time at the view

Comment: OK, please remove `render :thankyou` from the `:create` method.  Please post the edit form for this model if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try, in your app/views/home/thankyou.js.erb file:

```
$('#signup-modal .modal-body').html("<%= j render_to_string('thankyou') %>");
```

And in your `:create` action:

```
render js: :thankyou
```

Comment: I try using if block and now rails renders only once, but template is  still missing. I have the same render call in another function and it works fine

Comment: Do you actually have an action in the controller here called :thankyou, or just a template called thankyou.html.erb or whatever?

Comment: Oh.. well, typically you wouldn't render a partial directly from a controller.  You would have the partial inside a view like this: `<%= render 'thankyou' %>` or whatever in some conditional.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have understood the issue. After the render to  _thankyou rails looks for a view called thankyou. If i add a file called thankyou.html.erb i have no errors. I don't know why rails search this view after the render

Comment: Well, partials are prefixed with _ (underscore) and are typically loaded from inside a view and contain part of the page.  If you call `render` in a view it will want to render a partial. If you call it in a controller, it expects a view, meaning a template with no underscore.

Comment: I get it, but i have the same code in another function and it works fine

Comment: In the same controller? You call `redirect_to action: :thankyou` and all you have is a partial? Very weird.

Comment: Yes in the same controller.

Comment: I added an explanation of your problem above my answer.

Comment: Yes it makes sense. But unfortunately i have the same problem also with render instead of redirect_to

Comment: Are you still using `render action: :checkout`?  Or `render :checkout` in your `:create`?

Comment: I'm using render :checkout and render :thankyou. From the log it seems rails calls action create twice

Comment: Can you post an updated version of your `:create` reflecting what you currently have in place?

Comment: What routes do you have that might lead to that action?

Comment: Could you possibly paste in the relevant area of the logs?

Comment: You could try throwing a `return` after your `if` block.

Comment: In my routes file i have post '/create' => 'home#create'. I put the log file in the question

Comment: If i remove render at the end rails searchs a view called create and obviously doesn't finds it. I've pasted the form that calls the action create

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the thanyou template like so:

```
def create
    amount = params[:amount]
    nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
    render action: :checkout and return unless nonce
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    amount: amount,
    payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
    render :thankyou
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is simply called twice.
You have to check why on the client side. 
You will probably see two calls in the developer console of your browser.

Comment: You are right. I see two calls. The first has type xhr, the second is a document. I shoul have only the second

Comment: Then you need to share us the code of the page. the error is in there.

Comment: I've pasted the code of the form that calls the function create

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that removing *remote: true*. Now i have only one call (HTML). I have also deleted the partial *_checkout.html.erb* and i have replaced with a file called *checkout.html.erb*